# Reminders/Expirations docusign mail subjects and bodies

Tags: docusignapi

We are trying to customise the subjects and bodies of such emails as Reminder and Expiration. By default it always prepends *Reminder: and Expiration:*
before the initial subject.

**The xml structure is following**

```
<data …>
[[Conditional:IsExpirationMail]]Expiration:
[[Conditional:IsReminderMail]]Reminder:
[Data:InputSubject]
</data>
```

But in our custom case we want to create a custom subject either for reminder or expiration mails without any connection to the subject which was sent when envelope was created. Is it somehow possible to build some conditions to do that?

And the second question is about how to properly create bodies for both of mails mentioned above. Without borrowing default body?

Answer (score -1):

The option that exists for altering what a recipient sees is driven by the resource files DocuSign provides.
The documentation on altering the resource files is found here:
https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&bundleId=pik1583277475390&topicId=yum1583277332870.html&_LANG=enus

The email resource file guide which you would need to alter is found here: https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&bundleId=docusign-email-resource-file-guide&topicId=docusign-email-resource-file-guide.pdf&_LANG=enus

You can create your own email body by searching through the resource file for the relevant sections and altering them to your standard. The resource file is thousands of lines of XML which can make finding the correct part to alter a bit challenging but often times searching for key text values found on the email will show the corresponding XML you'd want to alter.